# I know the basic definition of continuity. But here, the definition is applied for a ball.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am studying the topology of $\Bbb R^n$ from W. R . Wade's Introduction to analysis book.

I know the basic definition of continuity. But here, the definition is applied for a "ball".

I dont understand the section which i have underlined with a blue pencil.

How do we rewrite the definition for a ball?

Please can you explain this to me in a more clear way?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The open ball $B_\delta(a)$ is defined to be the set of all points whose distance from $a$ is less than $\delta$:

$$B_\delta(a)=\{x:d(x,a)<\delta\}\;,$$

where $d(x,a)$ is the distance from $x$ to $a$. In the real line we normally define distance using the absolute value function: $d(x,a)=|x-a|$. Thus, $x\in B_\delta(a)$ just means that $|x-a|<\delta$. Similarly, $f(x)\in B_\epsilon(f(a))$ just means that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. Here’s the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition:

> The function $f:E\to\Bbb R$ is continuous as $a\in E$ if and only if given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ and $x\in E$ imply that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

If we make the substitutions that I indicated, it becomes:

> The function $f:E\to\Bbb R$ is continuous as $a\in E$ if and only if given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $x\in E\cap B_\delta(a)$ implies that $f(x)\in B_\epsilon(f(a))$.

Now recall that $f[A]$ just means $\{f(x):x\in A\}$. In that second version of the definition we’re saying that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if

$$\{f(x):x\in E\cap B_\delta(a)\}\subseteq B_\epsilon(f(a))\;,$$

i.e., if

$$f[E\cap B_\delta(a)]\subseteq B_\epsilon(f(a))\;.$$

Thus, we can further rewrite it thus:

> The function $f:E\to\Bbb R$ is continuous as $a\in E$ if and only if given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f[E\cap B_\delta(a)]\subseteq B_\epsilon(f(a))$.

Comment: You wrote more instructive and explicit. Thank you:) I got:)

Comment: @B11b: You’re welcome; I’m glad it helped.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have something interesting to tell you.

Answer (score 3):

The passage you highlighted merely translates the standard definition into the new terminology of balls. First let's not worry about maps from a set $E$ but just maps $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

The standard definition: $f$ is continuous at $a$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

Now, let's translate this. The phrase "$|x-a|<\delta$" exactly means $x\in B_\delta(a)$. And similarly, the phrase "$|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$" exactly means $f(x)\in B_\epsilon(f(a))$. So we require that $f$ takes anything in $B_\delta(a)$ into $B_\epsilon(f(a))$, or in other words, $f(B_\delta(a))\subset B_\epsilon(f(a))$.

Thus, the condition for continuity of $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ can be translated to: $f$ is continuous at $a$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $f(B_\delta(a))\subset B_\epsilon(f(a))$.

Now, if you're looking at a function $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$, then you need to intersect $B_\delta(a)$ with $E$ in order to restrict the domain.

Comment: Yes I understand well. Rıght Now I am seeing the conversion:) thank you for help:)

Answer (score 1):

What your book calls $B_r(a)$, where $a$ is in a metric space $X$, is the set of the elements of $X$ whose distance to $a$ is smaller than $r$.

In other terms, $$B_r(a) = \{x \in X : d(x,a)<r\}.$$
if $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, then we can take modulus as a good distance, and define $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.

Can you see where the connexion is now ?

Comment: Thank you for help. Sorry, but ıt ıs so complicated for me. So I cannot reply your question. Sorry again:(

Comment: No problem ! I'm confident that once you've finished studting the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ it won't be that complicated. What you can remember from my answer is the definition of a ball : $B_r(a) = \{x  : |x-a|<r\}$